# How to implement the auto-complete word hint in Android?

Tags: android, autocomplete

Is there any means to implement the auto-complete word hint in Android, with the word hint retrieved from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String[] COUNTRIES = { "Afganistan", "Algeria", "Albania",
        "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua and\nBarbuda", "Argentina",
        "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
        "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCountry);

    countryNames = COUNTRIES; // this is where you would fire a loader
    // and set the adapter when you get a result, so the following would be in a callback
    ed.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countryNames));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the Autocomplete textview

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:completionThreshold="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidAutoCompleteTextView.java

```
package com.AndroidAutoCompleteTextView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class AndroidAutoCompleteTextView extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;
String item[]={
  "January", "February", "March", "April",
  "May", "June", "July", "August",
  "September", "October", "November", "December"
};

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);

       myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(this);
       myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));

   }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
  int after) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: what a pity! i cannot access this link, maybe it is blocked.